# Import external Viewbox to UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl where I want to add a Viewbox. The Viewbox is in an other xaml-file in my project. I tried a lot (something like ResourceDictionaries) ... but failed. Here is my minimal example:

**UserControl:**

```
<UserControl ......>
  <Grid>
  <!--Here I want the Viewbox (MyPicture.xaml)-->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MyPicture.xaml**

```
<Viewbox Width="16" Height="16" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Rectangle ... />
</Viewbox>
```

Hope anybody can help me.

Comment: You don't have anything else in the `MyPicture.xaml` file? What is the rationale behind this idea?

Comment: No nothing else. I only want to keep this ViewBox in an external file.

Comment: So you can't use `ResourceDictionary` nor control / user control? It's really interesting why did you decide to use this approach.

Comment: My plan is to split different viewboxes in different files. So it´s easier to change them and reuse in other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you need to re-use the view box, if so please try the next solution as a start point to your research.

**Xaml code:**

```
<Window x:Class="ResourceDictionaryProblemHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateWithViewBox}"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateWithViewBox}"></ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplateWithViewBox}"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

**Resource dictionary code**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateWithViewBox">
    <Viewbox Width="16" Height="16">
        <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Tomato" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"></Rectangle>
    </Viewbox>
</DataTemplate>
```

**App.xaml code**

```
<Application x:Class="ResourceDictionaryProblemHelpAttempt.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
     <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <ResourceDictionary Source="ViewPortContainingResourceDictionary.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In the resource dictionary code, instead of using  (code) , I want to just call the viewbox file. Especially since I have like 2000 lines of code and 30 different view box files. For example, it would be something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateWithViewBox">
    Get file information of viewbox1.xaml
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplateWithViewBox2">
    Get file information of viewbox2.xaml
</DataTemplate>
```